# Why importing file from another project module not working?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have maven project with 2 modules.

```
root-folder:
- sub-module1:
.... - src
.... - pom.xml

-sub-module2:
.... - src
.... - pom.xml

- pom.xml
```

For example, i have some `Test1` class from `sub-module1`. And in `sub-module2` i have another class `Test2`. Trying to use `Test1` in `Test2`, but second module cannot resolve import. What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you add a dependency to sub-module1 in sub-module2/pom.xml?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev yes, but i can re-check it. Maybe it somehow not applied.

Comment: Hmm... It was not in dependencies. Looks like some bug with my maven repo...

Answer (score 0):

In the main pom.xml, you need to add modules like below

```
    <modules>
    <module>artifact-id-of-module-1</module>
    <module>artifact-id-of-module-2</module>
    </modules>
```

And in the `pom.xml` of the second module, you need to add dependency like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>parent-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-id-of-module-1</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will enable you to access all the class of module1 in module 2.